# xslt apply-templates in second level

Tags: xslt

I cannot wrap `<panel>` tags to second level individual items as shown in Expected result bellow. Instead I get all 1.x element values into a single  node with the xslt i have written bellow. Please help me.

### Source xml

```
    <root>
    <step id="1">
        <content>
            <text>
                1.0 Sample first level step text
            </text>
        </content>
        <content/>
        <step>
            <content>
                <text>
                    1.1 Sample second level step text
                </text>
            </content>
        </step>
        <step>
            <content>
                <text>
                    1.2 Sample second level step text
                </text>
            </content>
        </step>
        <step>
            <content>
                <text>
                    1.3 Sample second level step text
                </text>
            </content>
        </step>
    </step>
    <step id="2">
        <content>
            <text>
                2.0 Sample first level step text
            </text>
        </content>
        <content/>
        <step>
            <content>
                <text>
                    2.1 Sample second level step text
                </text>
            </content>
        </step>
        <step>
            <content>
                <text>
                    2.2 Sample second level step text
                </text>
            </content>
        </step>
        <step>
            <content>
                <text>
                    2.3 Sample second level step text
                </text>
            </content>
        </step>
    </step>
</root>
```

### Expected output

```
<panel>
    <panel>
        <panel>
            1.0 Sample first level step text
        </panel>
        <panel>
            1.1 Sample second level step text
        </panel>
        <panel>
            1.2 Sample second level step text
        </panel>
        <panel>
            1.3 Sample second level step text
        </panel>
    </panel>
    <panel>
        <panel>
            2.0 Sample first level step text
        </panel>
        <panel>
            2.1 Sample second level step text
        </panel>
        <panel>
            2.2 Sample second level step text
        </panel>
        <panel>
            2.3 Sample second level step text
        </panel>
    </panel>
</panel>
```

### My XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <panel>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </panel>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/step" >
    <panel>
        <panel>
            <xsl:apply-templates select ="content/text/node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </panel>
        <panel>
            <xsl:apply-templates select ="step/content/text/node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </panel>
    </panel>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think you have accepted the wrong answer. THere are some bad examples in it. On the other side, the solution of @Alejandro is short and elegant -- quite in the spirit of XSLT.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The trick is usage `//` accessor

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <panel>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='//text'/>
    </panel>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text" >
        <panel>
            <xsl:apply-templates select ="./node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </panel>
</xsl:template>
```

place expected formatting instead of my `node()`

**EDITED**
To handle grouping as you ask, add one more

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <panel>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='/root/step' mode="root"/>
    </panel>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="step" mode="root"><!-- mode allows distinguish another tag 'step'-->
     <panel> <!-- now we can convert tree to planar -->
         <xsl:apply-templates select='//text'/>
     </panel>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text" >
        <panel>
            <!-- format text from node text there -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select ="text()"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </panel>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the response. One more thing, maybe I don’t get this XSLT at all!. How can I add another <panel> grouping at <step id=1> level. Please refer initial Source XML and Expected output in my post.

Comment: This is *terrible* XSLT code. I approve of whoever downvoted this answer. Look at the solution of @Alejandro. It is really clean and elegant.

Comment: Ah, I see, we're not flattening the tree all the way. (Deleted prev comment.)

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > 

 <xsl:template match="root|root/step|text"> 
   <panel> 
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
   </panel> 
 </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit**: If you want to beautify the things a bit, add this template:

```
 <xsl:template match="text()"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/> 
 </xsl:template>
```

**Edit 2**: I've change the pattern according new input and output document. This is in case of any other wound may need it.

Comment: Thank you all for the response. One more thing, maybe I don’t get this XSLT at all!. How can I add another <panel> grouping at <step id=1> level. Please refer initial Source XML and Expected output in my post. –

Comment: I think i got it. Thanks.
 <xsl:template match="root|root/step|text">
  <panel>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </panel>
 </xsl:template>